# Alexa skill image not showing

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I am writing a simple skill and I want to show a full screen image. I found a piece of example code on the [Alexa skill pages](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/include-a-card-in-your-skills-response.html)

```
def build_speechlet_response(title, output, reprompt_text, should_end_session):
return {
"outputSpeech": {"type":"PlainText","text":"This is your cow!"},
"card": {
  "type": "Standard",
  "title": "Cow picture",
  "text": "This is your cow",
  "image": {
    "smallImageUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/icepick-alexa/cow.jpg",
    "largeImageUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/icepick-alexa/cow.jpg"
           }
       } 
}
```

I know for a fact my image hosting is okay, because when I use a template I can show the image as a background image.. but I just want it fulscreen and not as a background.

This code works fine in the alexa skill online simulator and I see the image there. However when I run the code on my Alexa Echo Spot it shows the text but no image. I tried different images in different sizes but it doesnt help.

Comment: Worst case scenario: Convert your images to ascii art

Comment: https://manytools.org/hacker-tools/convert-images-to-ascii-art/

Comment: Hmmm the images are dynamic.. converting to ascii is not desired and i think should be a requirement to show them..

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post this as a comment but couldn't because my reputation isn't high enough.

You're seeing the image in the simulater because it's setup to simulate the Echo Show. Your code needs to be optimized based on the device's type. Check [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/display-interface-reference.html) for more information

Answer (score 1):

If you are using alexa-sdk then here is a code snippet to help you show full screen image on spot. If you are not using sdk then you can refer only to the JSON part of this snippet.

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');
```

Create Image object if you are using Alexa SDK.

```
const myImage = new Alexa.ImageHelper().withDescription('Image').addImageInstance(IMG_URL_PATH + 'Image.jpg').getImage();
```

Body Template 1 with background that acts like a full screen image.

```
var displayTemplate = {
    type: 'BodyTemplate1',
    token: 'Your Token',
    backButton: 'hidden',
    backgroundImage: myImage,
    title: '',
    textContent: {
        primaryText : {
            type : 'RichText',
            text : '<div align=\'center\'><br/><br/><br/><br/><font size=\'2\'>Some Text</font></div>'
        }
    }    
};
```

Inside your Handler you can return a response in following way.

```
handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(speechText).addRenderTemplateDirective(displayTemplate).getResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

To display an image in your alexa skill, you can use the Standard card as a method to implement it. 
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/display-cards-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the display templates to render an image along with some text. Also, if you wish to have just an image, go for "card" method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the simple alexa function to display the card - 
1. askWithCard
2. tellWithCard
3. Use display Templates